# Is it possible to randomly access specific index value in serialized array stored in a file in Java?

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to access an array index position in a serialized array object file. I do not want to deserialize the whole array object and then access the array. I have been able to do it in C++ using seekg, but have not been successful in Java.

---

I have tried using the RandomAccessFile [please see the following code], but I am not able to access the specific location in array and convert it to the actual value [see code comment- //Random Access Reading (Read specific position)].
Let me know the solution for this problem.

Code-

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Bitmaps implements Serializable
{
    int bitmapArray[] = new int[5];

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bitmaps [bitmapArray=" + Arrays.toString(bitmapArray) + "]";
    }
}
public class RandomAccess2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Bitmaps bitmaps = new Bitmaps();

            String filename = "blocksinfo.txt";
            String workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            String FILEPATH = workingDirectory + "\\" + filename;  //C:\\Users\ashis\workspace\hackerrank1\src\hackerrank1\blocksinfo.txt';

            //Initialize array with 100....104
            int cnt=100;
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                bitmaps.bitmapArray[i]=cnt++;


            //Serialize array and store in a file
            serializeObject(bitmaps, FILEPATH);
            int objLength = sizeof(bitmaps);  //function to calculate size of serialized array
            System.out.println("Length in bytes after serialization=>"+objLength);


            //System.out.println(new String(readFromFile(FILEPATH, 0, ewahBitmap1.sizeInBytes())));

            try {

                //Random Access Reading (Read all contents)
                byte[] byteArray = readFromFile(FILEPATH, 0, objLength);
                ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
                Bitmaps bitmaps2 = (Bitmaps) is.readObject();
                System.out.println("Full Random Access Reading=>"+bitmaps2);


                //Random Access Reading (Read specific position)
                byte[] byteArray1 = readFromFile(FILEPATH, 98, 2);
                ByteArrayInputStream in1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray1);
                ObjectInputStream is1 = new ObjectInputStream(in1);
                int val = (int) is1.readObject();
                System.out.println("Partial Random Access Reading=>"+val);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //writeToFile(FILEPATH, ewahBitmap1.toString(), 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static byte[] readFromFile(String filePath, int position, int size)
            throws IOException {

        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
        file.seek(position);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        file.read(bytes);
        file.close();
        return bytes;

    }

    public static void serializeObject(Object bitmap, String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(bitmap);
        oos.close();

    }

    public static int sizeof(Object obj) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOutputStream);

        objectOutputStream.writeObject(obj);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        objectOutputStream.close();

        return byteOutputStream.toByteArray().length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible. It's not a random-access format. You have to deserialize the array and then in index it in memory.